# Integer constant / callable duality of variable in R

Tags: r

I've come across this snippet of code in an R package:

```
if (msLevel != 2 || (msLevel == 2 & !any(msLevel(x) == 2))) {
    ...
}
```

How can `msLevel` be both an integer constant equal to 2, and a function that can be applied to a variable `x`? (Here `msLevel` is a function parameter with the default assignment `2L`.)

(Related question: should R be considered an [esoteric programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language)? )

Comment: in R you can have a function and a variable with the same name. this cannot work in python for example. So you need to be careful

Comment: R is quirky -- but it would be a stretch to call it esoteric as anything other than a joke (which is what I suspect you intended).

Comment: I cannot imagine a situation where `msLevel == 2 & !any(msLevel(x) == 2)` would be `TRUE`. Can someone make an example? Also, can you provide context to the question - where did you find this?

Comment: The line comes from [here](https://rdrr.io/bioc/xcms/src/R/functions-XCMSnExp.R#sym-chromPeakSpectra). I assume it's saying, if the user requested `msLevel == 2`, and the vector `x` does not contain any elements of level 2, then ...